# Minimax optimal multiple hypothesis test

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, learning-theory

Let us consider the following two-player game
between Chooser and Guesser.
There is a finite set $\Omega$
and $k$ probability distributions
on $\Omega$, denoted by $
\mathcal{P}
=\{P_1,\ldots,P_k\}
$.

Chooser picks a distribution $Q\in
\mathcal{P}
$
and presents an $X\in\Omega$ drawn according to $Q$
to Guesser. Guesser has pre-committed to a function
$\psi:\Omega\to\mathcal{P}$
according to which he will infer
the identity of $Q$. The loss suffered by the
Guesser is the probability that his inference
is incorrect, under the Chooser's adaptive (worst-case) choice of $Q$:
$$
L(\psi) = 
\max_{Q\in P}
\sum_{x\in\Omega}Q(x)\boldsymbol{1}[
Q
\neq
\psi(x)
].
$$

We say that $\psi^*$ is minimax-optimal
(for $\mathcal{P}$)
if
$$
L(\psi^*) = \min_{
\psi\in
\mathcal{P}^\Omega
}
L(\psi).
$$

For binary hypothesis testing, it is an immediate consequence of the Neyman-Pearson Lemma that the maximum likelihood yields the minimax-optimal inference. Namely, for $k=2$,
the choice $\psi(x)=\mathrm{argmax}\{P_1(x),P_2(x)\}$
is easily seen to be minimax-optimal.
For $k=3$, this is no longer the case.
Indeed,
one can easily construct 3 distributions
$P_1,P_2,P_3$ such that for all $x\in\Omega$,
$P_3(x)\le \max\{P_1(x),P_2(x)\}$.
In this case, the choice
$\psi(x)=\mathrm{argmax}\{P_1(x),P_2(x),P_3(x)\}$
will never select $P_3$, and hence the adaptive
adversary will always choose $Q=P_3$
for a maximal loss of $1$.

*Question.* What is known about this problem?
What is known about minimax decision rule
for $k>2$?

Update: My claims about the implications of the Neyman-Pearson Lemma are incorrect and in particular the maximum-likelihood $\psi$ is not always minimax-optimal. See the answer by Mr X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deterministic $\Psi$ is bound to fail. You must randomize. Consider three probability measures supported on $\{1,2\}$. A deterministic $\Psi$ will have only two of the measures in its image. The adversary will choose the third, again yielding a loss of 1.  Once you allow $\Psi$ to be randomized, you have a zero sum game, which for small $\Omega$ can be solved quickly via linear programming.

Answer (score 2):

The argmax choice function minimizes the sum of errors for any $k$, but not the maximum of errors, even for $k=2$. In fact, minimizing the maximum of errors is $NP$-hard even for the case $P_1=P_2=P$: is this case you minimize over $\max\{x,1-x\}$ where $x$ is any subset sum of $P=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, so you're looking for the subset sum closest to $1/2$. This is a variant of the subset sum problem in which the target is half the total sum.

This variant is also $NP$-complete: given a general instance $x_1,....,x_n$ of the subset sum problem, we can reduce it to this case. First scale it so the total sum is $1/3$ and the target sum is $t<\frac{1}{3}$. Define $P=(x_1,..,x_n,\frac{1}{2}-t,\frac{1}{6}+t)$. It's total sum is 1. If a subset of $x_i$ sums to $t$, together with $\frac{1}{2}-t$ it will sum to 1. Conversely, take any subset of $P$. If it includes both $\frac{1}{2}-t,\frac{1}{6}+t$ it sums to at least $2/3$. If it includes neither of $\frac{1}{2}-t,\frac{1}{6}+t$ it sums to at most $1/3$. So to hit $1/2$, it must include exactly one of them, and we can assume it includes $\frac{1}{2}-t$ by taking complement in the other case. So the remaining elements from $x_1,...,x_n$ sum up to $t$.

Note that the instances we use are all degenrate: The goal of $\psi$ is to assess the distribution from the data. If $P_1=P_2$, the data clearly tells you nothing. The fact that the problem is $NP$-hard even in this degenerate case means that you probably want to answer a different question.

One good idea is to look at randomized strategies (as Yuval has suggested), and then finding the optinal strategy is easy with Linear Programming with $k|\Omega|+1$ variables: $k|\Omega|$ describing the non-deterministic $\psi$, and a final one smaller than the linear sums appearing in the maximum expression.